# How do I transfer files to android 2.2 running in VirtualBox? I have install fake sd card

Tags: android, ubuntu, virtualbox

I need to put some apk, and some documents in my android running in virtualbox. I have installed a fake sd card but i don't know how to transfer the files into the sd card. How do i do it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't tested this way, but maybe it work in Android 4.4

Transfer with Bluetooth

For this way you must have two bluetooth dongles, one of them for pc and another for virtual android.

For activate one of bluetooth dongles for android :

Open VirtualBox > Settings > USB > Add filter from device > select one of the bluetooth dongles > OK

Comment: Tested with Android 2.2-generic in vitual box with guest additions, enabled Bluetooth in USB Setting of Virtual Box and successfully shared files with .jpg extension. Open console(ALT + F1) and cd /sdcard/bluetooth and pm install blah.apk.jpg and Close console (ALT + F7).